# Row command with Link button in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two GridViews. GridView1 contains 2 link buttons in a column. When I select a link button in GridView1, the details of the link button should be displayed in GridView2.

GridView2 contains a column with radio buttons.  I need to fill the radio buttons dynamically from the database.

How can I fill the Radio button list of GridView2 by using GridView1_RowCommand?  Or Can I get it from the RowDataBound event of GridView2?

code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.CommandName == "Yes")
    {           
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        int RowIndex = gvRow.RowIndex;            
        Int32 iAppID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());               

        dset = userApps.UserSelectedApp(iUserID, iAppID);
        if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewRow gRow = GridView2.Rows[RowIndex];//I need to create object to this Gridview2, and fill the radiobutton list with some values
            RadioButtonList rdbtnSubPlans = (RadioButtonList)e.gRow.Cells[2].FindControl("rdbSubPlans");

            ds = userApps.UpgradePlans(iUserID, iAppID);
            if (ds != null)
            {
                rdbtnSubPlans.DataSource = ds;
                rdbtnSubPlans.DataValueField = "PlanID";
                rdbtnSubPlans.DataTextField = "Plans";
                rdbtnSubPlans.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "No")
    {}
     dtset = user.UserSelectedAppication(iUserID, iAppID);    
     GridView2.DataSource = dtset;
     GridView2.DataBind();
     MultiView1.SetActiveView(viewRenewOrUpdate);                
    }
}
```

ASPX code for the GridViews

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ApplicationID" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
    OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="l1" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        < Some Bound Fields>                                                   
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" 
                    CssClass="lnkbtn" Visible="false" commandname="Yes" Width="100px" >
                </asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNo" runat="server" CssClass="lnkbtn" Text="No" 
                    Visible="false" commandname="No" ToolTip="No and Yes current plan" Width="100px" >
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>                                                        
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>                                               
</asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ApplicationID"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicationName" HeaderText="Application name">
            <HeaderStyle Width="30%" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="col" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plans">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbSubPlans" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbSubPlan_OnSelectedIndexChanged" Enabled="false">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="col" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: I need to get the radio button list in the GridView2. I am getting an error like **System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'gRow' and no extension method 'gRow' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Comment: The RowCommand event is of **GridView1**, Based on the selected link button of GridView1 I need to fill a column of **GridView2** with radio button list.

Comment: can you show your aspx page Gridviews html

Comment: why is your if (e.CommandName == "No") inside if (e.CommandName == "Yes") body?

Comment: There is a similar code with minor changes. that is the reason why I did not included in  if (e.CommandName == "No") . Did you understood the Issue ? I have added aspx code. Check it once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43266/discussion-between-irfan-tahirkheli-and-sanjeev4evr)

Comment: There is an unmatched curly brace in your C# code.  Could you show your actual code?  Code that compiles, and can be used to repeat the problem?

Comment: Thank you for finding it..I rectified it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill Gridview2 first, and then do the following corrections:

```
GridViewRow gRow = GridView2.Rows[0]
RadioButtonList rdbtnPlans = (RadioButtonList)gRow.FindControl("rdbPlans");
```